# Unable to sculpt a cube

Tags: sculpting, sculpt

I wanted to practice with the sculpting tools, so I tried them on the starting cube but none of them do anything I think? Or if they're doing anything it's not inherently noticeable.

Comment: Did you subdivide the cube? If you didn't add enough geometry to sculpt, it won't do anything unless you click on the corners of it. Make sure to either turn on dyntopo at the top right of the sculpting viewport or add a subdivision surface in the modifiers tab, or just subdivide the cube in edit mode.

Comment: :O Okay that worked thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nascent Space's comment](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/187624/unable-to-sculpt-a-cube#comment314511_187624):

> If you didn't add enough geometry to sculpt, it won't do anything unless you click on the corners of it. Make sure to either turn on dyntopo at the top right of the sculpting viewport or add a subdivision surface in the modifiers tab, or just subdivide the cube in edit mode.